# Joomla 3 - не устанавливаются компоненты

Tags: joomla

Поставил Joomla 3, пытаюсь установить компонент отсюда http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/1.5/Introduction 
всеми способами: и архив выбирая, и путь прописывая, и с удаленного веб-сервера - во всех случаях пишет:

> Warning
>
> JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find Joomla XML setup file

Хотя xml-файл там есть. В чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 1):

Версия 1.5, а ты на 3-ю версию пытаешься установить.

Comment: Есть способ, как установить на 3?